# PHP Check For File Name then Upload a File

Tags: php, html

Hello and Thanks for the help!

I have Html and PHP file (2 different file):

**html:**

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>File Uploading Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="Upload_File.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000" />
<input name="uploadedfile" id="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Process File" Onclick="__set(document.getElementById('uploadedfile').value);" style="background-color: hsla(240, 100%, 75%,0.3);font-weight: bold;"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Php:**

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>File Uploading Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="Upload_File.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000" />
<input name="uploadedfile" id="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" Onclick="__set(document.getElementById('uploadedfile').value);" style="background-color: hsla(240, 100%, 75%,0.3);font-weight: bold;"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
$uploadOk = 1;
$target_path_file = "Upload_Files_All/";
$N=$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'];
$target_path = $target_path_file . basename($N);
$size=$_FILES['uploadedfile']['size'];
$FileTypeExt = pathinfo($target_path,PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
if (isset($N))
 {
   if (empty($N))
      {
       echo "<p style='color:#ff0000;' >Please choose a file to Upload</p>";
      }
   else
      {
       if ($uploadOk==1)
         {
           if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path))
                {
                 echo "<strong>The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])." is ready to upload</strong>";
                }
            else
                {
                echo "<p style='color:#ff0000;' >There was an error uploading the file, please Contact Administrator</p>";
                }
        }
        
      }
    
}
?>
```

Now I want to upload files to the system
files name:
sample.xlsx
sample1.xlsx

How I modify the code that only files with the same name (sample.xlsx or sample1.xlsx) will be uploaded.
and file with different name give the user message "please change file name"

Comment: do you want to refuse the upload for other filenames, or do you want to discard the upload ?

Comment: refuse the upload thanks! and give the user message "please change file name"

Comment: you can do this strict with html5 just by checking the filename in the browser. And there is the other method to upload it and discard it when it has bad filename

Comment: Hey thanks for help. i didn't understand php and I must use the same template

Answer (score 0):

There is a not so secure method using HTML5 and input/accept.
You can use it in a Intranet Application where security is not so important.

Such Things should always be checked by the server in production.

**DO NOT USE IT ON INTERNET**

Only combined with a server check.

Using XLSX Mime **application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet**

AND/OR XLS Mime, **application/msexcel**

```
<input name="uploadedfile" id="uploadedfile" type="file" accept="application/msexcel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" /><br />


<html>
<head>
<title>File Uploading Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="Upload_File.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000" />
<input name="uploadedfile" id="uploadedfile" type="file" accept="application/msexcel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" /><br />
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Process File" Onclick="__set(document.getElementById('uploadedfile').value);" style="background-color: hsla(240, 100%, 75%,0.3);font-weight: bold;"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

THE BETTER WAY

Is using the $_FILES variable
$_FILES['uploadedfile']['type'];
You can check the Mime Type

```
<?php
$uploadOk = 1;
$target_path_file = "Upload_Files_All/";

$accepted_mime1 = "application/msexcel";
$accepted_mime2 = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

$T=$_FILES['uploadedfile']['type'];
$N=$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'];

if($T != $accepted_mime1 && $T != $accepted_mime2){
// We do not accept it and we unset the $_FILES
    unset($_FILES);
}

$target_path = $target_path_file . basename($N);
$size=$_FILES['uploadedfile']['size'];
$FileTypeExt = pathinfo($target_path,PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
if (isset($N))
 {
   if (empty($N))
      {
       echo "<p style='color:#ff0000;' >Please choose a file to Upload</p>";
      }
   else
      {
       if ($uploadOk==1)
         {
           if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path))
                {
                 echo "<strong>The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])." is ready to upload</strong>";
                }
            else
                {
                echo "<p style='color:#ff0000;' >There was an error uploading the file, please Contact Administrator</p>";
                }
        }
        
      }
    
}
?>
```

Comment: `$_FILES['uploadedfile']['type']` can be spoofed easily as well

Comment: its for Intranet Application

Comment: thanks for help!!!! i don't understand php really good

Comment: It is possible because I have just given you a hint. you must check if the Mime is exactly like I suggested. place a `echo $_FILES['uploadedfile']['type']` in the code so you can see what the real mime is. then you can continue to code

Comment: @DarkBee yes, it is true. I hope he is not using it in production.